# php error :Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

i'm trying the example in php (just begining to learn)

employee.php :

```
<?php
class Employee {
    private   $id;
    private   $name;
    private   $age;
    private   $address;
    private   $tax;
    private   $salary;

    public function __construct($name, $age, $address, $tax, $salary) {

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->address = $address;
        $this->tax = $tax;
        $this->salary = $salary;    
    }   
    public function __get($param) {
        return $this->$param;
    }   
    public function calculateSalary()
    {
        return $this->salary - ($this->salary * $this->tax / 100);
    }
}
```

---

index :

```
 <?php  
    require_once 'db.php';
    require_once 'employee.php';
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'address', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
            $salary = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'salary', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
            $tax = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'tax', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
     $params = array(  ':name' => $name,
                                       ':address' => $address,
                                       ':age' => $age,
                                       ':salary' => $salary,
                                       ':tax' => $tax);

            if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' && isset($_GET['id'])){
                        $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                        $sql = 'UPDATE employees SET name = :name ,address = :address ,  age = :age , salary = :salary, tax =:tax WHERE id = :id';
                        $params[':id'] = $id;
            } else {
                        $sql = 'INSERT INTO employees SET name = :name ,address = :address ,  age = :age , salary = :salary, tax =:tax ';
            }


            $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);

            if($stmt->execute($params) === true
               )
            {
                $message = 'Employee  ' . $name . ' saved successfully';
                header('Location: /advancedphp');
                exit;
            } else {
                $error = true;
                $message = 'Error saving employee ' . $name ;
            }
        }
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' && isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        if ($id > 0) {
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id = :id';
            $result = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $founduser = $result->execute(array(':id' => $id));
            if($founduser === true){
                $user = $result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Employee', array('name', 'age', 'address', 'tax', 'salary'));
                $user = array_shift($user);
            }
        }
    }

        //Reading from database back
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM employees';
        $stmt = $connection->query($sql);
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'Employee', array('name', 'age', 'address', 'tax', 'salary'));
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
        <title>PDO by example</title>


    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="empform">
                    <form class="appform" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Employee Information</legend>

                <?php if(isset($message)) { ?>
                <p class="message <?= isset($error) ? 'error' : ' ' ?>"><?= $message ?></p>

                <?php } ?>

                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="name">Employee Name</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input required type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Write the employee name " maxlength="50" value="<?= isset($user) ? $user->name : ' '  ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="age">Employee Age</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input required type="number" name="age" id="age" min="22" max="60" value="<?= isset($user) ? $user->age : ' '  ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="address">Employee Address</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input required type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Write the employee address " maxlength="100" value="<?= isset($user) ? $user->address : ' '  ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="salary">Employee Salary</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
/*line 105*/  <input required type="number" step="0.01" name="salary" id="salary" min="1500" max="9000" value="<?= isset($user) ? $user->salary : ' '  ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label for="tax">Employee Tax (%)</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input required type="number" step="0.01" name="tax" id="tax" min="1" max="5" value="<?= isset($user) ? $user->tax : ' '  ?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

            </fieldset>

        </form>
            </div>      
            <div class="employees">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                            <th>Tax (%)</th>
                            <th>Control</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>                 

                     <?php
                            if(false !== $result){
                                foreach ($result as $employee) {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?= $employee->name ?></td>
                            <td><?= $employee->age?></td>
                            <td><?= $employee->address ?></td>
                            <td><?= round($employee->calculateSalary()) ?> L.E</td>
                            <td><?= $employee->tax ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/advancedphp/?action=edit&id=<?= $employee->id ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                <a href="/advancedphp/?action=delete&id=<?= $employee->id ?>"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                    <?php
                                }
                            } else {
                    ?>
                    <td colspan="5"><p>Sorry, no employees to list</p></td>
                    <?php        
                            }
                    ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

the project works well .. but if i edit fields .. it updated with errors in name and address fields

`"<br /><b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject\advancedphp\index.php</b> on line <b>105</b><br />"`

as shown :

[image: error]
I noticed that the error happen on windows but it gone on linux and it run without errors
I don't know where is the wrong ...

(Sorry i'm begginer)

Comment: you should mention line number 105

Comment: sorry ... edit it .. it is on line <input required type="number" step="0.01" name="salary" id="salary" min="1500" max="9000" value="<?= isset($user) ? $user->salary : ' '  ?>">

Answer (score 0):

I do not see where you are instantiating your class `Employee`

The references to `$user` are checked by `isset()` but your references to `$employee` are not.  somewhere you must instantiate the class i.e.

```
$user = new Employee(stuff,here,as,required,by,constructor);
```

or

```
$employee = new Employee(stuff,here,as,required,by,constructor);
```

Comment: the class Employee in a separate file called employee.php ... and i call it `require_once 'employee.php';`